# Set the size of ggsave exactly

Tags: r, ggplot2, dpi

`R` question.

I got so confused by the `width`, `height`, `dpi` and `unit`.

Why the following two size different?

```
ggsave(filename = "foo.png",ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
    geom_point(size=2, shape=23),width = 5, height = 4, dpi = 300, units = "in", device='png')
```

and

```
ggsave(filename = "foo.png",ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
           geom_point(size=2, shape=23),width = 5, height = 4, dpi = 72, units = "in", device='png')
```

I set both of the picture's size 5 (inches) * 4 (inches). But why when I change the `dpi`, the size changes?

How to understand the relationship between `height`, `width`, `unit` and `dpi`?

Or how to translate these four parameters into unit of pixels, which is easier for me to understand?

Comment: "*how to translate these four parameters into unit of pixels*" set `units = "in"`, then you can multiply `height` by dpi or `width` by `dpi` to get pixels in the vertical and horizontal. [Wikipedia on dpi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch).

Comment: I think the size has to be set in terms of physical size to make sure font sizes stay consistent. If you set the size in pixels only, you don't know what size the text will be once you put it on a page with a certain physical size. And if you put both of your example plots on a page at the same physical size, the font sizes should be the same.

Comment: @Marius, I agree with you. I prefer physical size than pixels as well. It just confuse me that even I set physical size of 5 * 4, by changing dpi, which is not a physical size parameter, the .png plot size changes.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To understand why the DPI is important, consider these two plots:

```
ggsave(filename = "foo300.png", ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
           geom_point(size=2, shape=23) + theme_bw(base_size = 10),
       width = 5, height = 4, dpi = 300, units = "in", device='png')
ggsave(filename = "foo150.png", ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
           geom_point(size=2, shape=23) + theme_bw(base_size = 10),
       width = 10, height = 8, dpi = 150, units = "in", device='png')
```

The resulting files have the same pixel dimensions, but the font size in each is different. If you place them on a page with the same physical size as their `ggsave()` calls, the font size will be correct (i.e. 10 as in the `ggsave()` call). But if you put them on a page at the wrong physical size, the font size won't be 10. To maintain the same physical size and font size while increasing DPI, you have to increase the number of pixels in the image.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the * place them on a page with the same physical size as their*, I am a little confused... Say I am viewing both images in my system viewer, which will render them in the same-sized window. Should I decrease one window, to be half of the other one ? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou: If you're viewing the image files after saving, I think you want them to be in the same size window, because then they will have the same "physical size" on your monitor. The DPI is all about what the image will look like once it's actually printed out in a document, so it's hard to understand while viewing them on a computer.

Comment: @Marius can you let me know if we can increase the device size in R ? I have a Q posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756969/creating-large-image-collage-in-r-or-python

Answer (score 8):

The two examples you gave have the same image 'scaling' but different 'image quality', if you pull the saved png into a `.docx` file, drag them to the same size, you will see they are the same image with just different 'image quality'. So in this way, we understand `width and height` as image 'scaling' and `dpi` as 'image quality'.

**If you want to save a figure as you have seen in the preview window**, this would be the best practice:

1. ggplot first

```r
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
           geom_point(size=2, shape=23)
```

2. Check the figure in Rstudio Plots window, if not satisfied, click Zoom, drag the pop-out window to your preferred size
3. right click the figure and choose Inspect element

then you see the line

```html
<img id="plot" width="100%" height="100%" src="plot_zoom_png?width=214&amp;height=151">
```

The above line suggests that your best width is 2.14 and best height at 1.51

4. ggsave() what you have just seen

```r
ggsave(filename = "foo3.png",width = 2.14, height = 1.51, dpi = 300)
# set the dpi as journal requirement, now the dpi only changes image quality, not image content, default unit is 'in' inch
```

**If you want to shape your figure to fit a journal's need**, this would be the best practice:

1. Obtain parameters from the journal, for example width = 180mm, height =185mm following Nature [Link](https://www.nature.com/documents/NRJs-guide-to-preparing-final-artwork.pdf)
2. Create a new Figure window using that parameters

```r
# you only need noRStudioGD=TRUE if using Rstudio
dev.new(width = 90, height = 180, unit = "mm",noRStudioGD=TRUE)
#note that a new window will appear in your task bar
```

3. plot() or ggplot() and preview the figure in that window
4. ggsave() what you have seen

```r
ggsave(filename = "foo3.png",width = 90, height = 180, unit = "mm", dpi = 300)
```

Comment: This is a cool option, is there a way to do this automatically whitout having to manually inspect the element?

Comment: @CyG I guess the idea is to use this method to decide what width and height fit your image. It cannot be done automatically?

Comment: For many journals, the image width might be set, meaning that you can only choose the image height (and size of lines, etc.).

Comment: In my experience I used a different way. Using the parameters mentioned above, you may define a figure useful for one column, two column/full page width. These parameters are useful for almost all figures in differnt journal. However, I use a predefined windows e.g ````windows(5,5)```` and then trace plot for one column. I use ``windows(10,5)`` for 1x2 two plot layout.