# Adjust font size to size of plot device

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, resolution

Often I am in a position when I have to adjust the size of the output image. Unfortunately, it means that usually I have to adjust font size, to make things readable.

For example, if the following plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(stringi)

set.seed(1)

df <- tibble(
  x = stri_rand_strings(10, 20), 
  y = runif(10) * 10, 
  label = stri_rand_strings(10, 10)
)


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label)) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0))
```

is saved to 12'' x 6'' image things look pretty good:

```
p + ggsave("test_small.png", width = 12, height = 6, unit = "in")
```

[12'' x 6'' output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG8Qk.png)

[image]

however if I increase dimensions to 36'' x 18'' the fonts are unreadble:

```
p + ggsave("test_large.png", width = 36, height = 18, unit = "in")
```

[36'' x 18''](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsGMR.png)

[image]

Is there any general strategy which allows us to change output resolution without constant tinkering with the font sizes?

Comment: Are trying to maintain the same scale of text size to page size? They are readable when you look at the "true" size of the page, since they both use `pt 10` font (I think that's the default). One way would be to define a ratio beforehand, but I don't believe `ggplot` will scale the font relative to output size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711236/r-how-to-set-the-size-of-ggsave-exactly

Comment: It's a very strange way to use `ggsave()` I'd say. You should set the text size in ggplot too e.g. `+ theme_bw(base_size = 16)`.

Comment: @Anonymouscoward That's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Answer is [here] (https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/) . You should simply add `showtext_opts(dpi = 300)` then create and save your plot.

Answer (score 6):

You need to define the size of your text items as well as the plotting environment.

Since you want to dynamically scale it will likely be easiest to scale your fonts and save sizes to the same values. See [ggplot2 - The unit of size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311917/ggplot2-the-unit-of-size) for the  divide by 2.834646 value to correct for font sizes.

```
base = 6 # set the height of your figure (and font)
expand = 2 # font size increase (arbitrarily set at 2 for the moment)

 ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
   geom_text(aes(label = label), size = base * expand / 2.834646) +
   scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0, size = base * expand ),
     axis.text.y = element_text(size = base * expand )) 

ggsave("test_large.png", width = base * 2, height = base, unit = "in", dpi = 300)
```