# How show graph on full screen?

Tags: r, ggplot2, background-image

I am plotting a graph using `ggplot2`. It has background image as my screen wall paper I want to plot graph over it and render it as `png` image.And I want my graph to fit on my computer screen.How can I  do that.When I am plotting it scales the image to smaller to fit in the graph!!

```
b <-readPNG("ao.png")
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(ms,x=x,y=-y)) + background_image(b) +
  geom_path(color='blue') + geom_point(color='blue')
p
```

I am using this code, image is screen-shot of my screen and in the output it is scaled to fit into the graph!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting an image to ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917049/inserting-an-image-to-ggplot2)

Comment: I know how to insert image in background I want to render it in png format  and that png should have x and y axis coinciding with screen rectangle

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711236/set-the-size-of-ggsave-exactly

Comment: you need to know your screen dimensions and the resolution that you are using, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like

```
png(file="saving_plot1.jpeg",with=800,height=600) # check the parameters
p # your plot
dev.off()
```

or you could use the plot pane and then use "export"