# How can I adjust the width of bar plots with different numbers of columns for consistent presentation in Word?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, width, ggsave

I am currently trying of saving several plots to put them in my word document for presentation. Some bar plots have 4 columns, others have 8. I would like to adapt the size of the bar plots with only 4 or 5 columns, so that they are only have of the width as the bar plots with 8 bars. In other words: In my word document all the plots should have about the same height, where as the width of the plots should vary depending on the number of columns.

I tried to follow the instructions on [Set the size of ggsave exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711236/set-the-size-of-ggsave-exactly) but I can change the height or width in ggsave() to any number and if I put the saved plots into word it doesn't make any difference.

```r
ggsave(ggsave(file = "plot_9.jpeg",
              plot = plot_9,
              width = 8, height = 9, units = "cm",
              dpi = 300))
ggsave(ggsave(file = "plot_9.jpeg",
              plot = plot_9,
              width = 5, height = 9, units = "cm",
              dpi = 300))
```

[image: resulting histogram]

Comment: * I mean "half of the width" not "have of the width"

Comment: Any reason you are wrapping `ggsave` inside another `ggsave`? Using `ggsave(ggsave(...))` will export the last plot using the default settings for width and height.

Comment: Ohhh nooo! That actually is the solution. I looked it over and over and couln't find the mistake. Thank you very much for looking at my question. Silly mistake..