# ggsave is ignoring my specification for height and width

Tags: r, ggplot2, ms-word, image-size, ggsave

I am trying to save a ggplot graph for a publication with specific criteria. Whenever I go about saving the plot using ggsave setting the height, width, units and DPI I get an image that is always larger.

I went and tried with another dataset, the iris dataset, and I still have the same issue. Here is my code below.

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species,y = Mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",color = "black",fill = "lightgrey") 
ggsave("Example.jpeg",height = 3,width = 5,units = "in",dpi = 600)
```

This is what the image size says in word after I insert the image. I would have expected the original size to be 3 inches tall and 5 inches wide.
[Saved Graph in Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBl6r.png)

Comment: Word may be resizing the image to fit the width of your page, and reporting the formatted size. Can you verify that the image file itself is 3000x1800 pixels?

Comment: I am no `{ggplot2}` expert; maybe, `height` and `width` correspond to an outer margin of the plot? Note the relation to `dpi`. However, this seems related and, at least to my understanding, proposes work arounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711236/set-the-size-of-ggsave-exactly

Comment: I think the issue is that Word is ignoring your image's specification. It has the dpi you specified, but not every program respects the dpi/size -- the only thing you have reliable control over is the resolution.

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711236/set-the-size-of-ggsave-exactly

Answer (score 0):

If you specify in `ggplot2` a 3 by 5 inch (height x width) image with 600 dpi, the resulting jpeg-file will have 1800x3000 pixels. I crossvalidated your reprex using a png-file as requested output image (see below).

```
library (magick)

img <- image_read("Example.png")
image_attributes(img)                  

                   property                               value
1                date:create                     2024-03-08T10:48:06+00:00
2                date:modify                     2024-03-08T10:48:06+00:00
3             date:timestamp                     2024-03-08T10:48:16+00:00
4                   png:bKGD chunk was found (see Background color, above)
5    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig                                             8
6         png:IHDR.bit_depth                                             8
7   png:IHDR.color-type-orig                                             2
8        png:IHDR.color_type                                 2 (Truecolor)
9  png:IHDR.interlace_method                            0 (Not interlaced)
10     png:IHDR.width,height                                    3000, 1800
11                  png:pHYs             x_res=23622, y_res=23622, units=1
```

However, and that's the important part here, the png-file has 600dpi while the jpeg-file only has 96dpi on my machine. The reason for that seems to be that, according to the `ggsave` documentation, the dpi argument only applies to 'raster output types', obviously not supporting jpeg-files yet.

Regarding the output for a journal, usually the request is limited to a minimum resolution (usually around 300 dpi) and certain supported image formats. Thus, the easiest workaround would be to see if they also accept png-files and go from there, using 600dpi if you want to:

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Set working directory
setwd ("yourwd")

# Image processing and saving using pipe
(
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species,y = Mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black",fill = "lightgrey")
) %>%
ggsave("Example.png", ., height = 3, width = 5, units = "in", dpi=600, device = "png")
```

Make sure not to oversee `, .,` in the last line.